# AngularJs: grab compiled html and set into tooltip

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, angularjs-ng-repeat, angular-ui

I'm using angular js bootstrap tooltip to show tooltips on a set of elements.

Plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/9xk41f3CR0wnajN71bSi

I need to inject into the tooltip html compiled by angular, but i don't really get how. The tooltip tutorial is not useful to me because it gets the html from the scope as variable, but for a set of elements this is not possible.

How can i fill `tooltip-html-unsafe`?

Comment: where do you want html to come from? Property of scope item?

Comment: no, an html template. Something that can't really stand in a property :(
the example was really too simple, maybe i'll update it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do something like this:

HTML:

```
<li ng-repeat="phone in phones">      
       <div phone-info index="{{$index}}">
         <p tooltip-html-unsafe="{{tooltips[$index]  }}">A tooltip should appear on top of this line ({{ phone.name }} - {{ phone.snippet }})</p>         
       <div>
</li>
```

Add to controller:

```
$scope.tooltips = [];
```

Directive:

```
app.directive('phoneInfo', function($compile, $timeout) {
  /* wrap in root element so we can get final innerHTML*/
  var tipTemplate = '<div><p> This will be the content of {{phone.name}} injected in the tooltip </p><div>';

  return {
    link: function(scope, el, attrs) {
      var tipComp = $compile(tipTemplate)(scope)
      $timeout(function() {
        scope.tooltips[attrs.index] = tipComp.html()

      });
    }
  }
})
```

Used `index` to avoid creating an isolated scope. Can also be done with isolated scope and create a property of `phone` instead of using `scope.tooltips[index]`

<kbd>**[DEMO](http://plnkr.co/edit/GG5VOIIZdtLiH7g3DuUH?p=preview)**</kbd>

Comment: thank you, it's very helpful. With an isolated scope (as you suggest) will you have something like `scope.phone.tooltip = tipComp.html()`?

Comment: yes...would just pass in `phone` to directive scope from `phone` attribute to do it that way. I don't like creating isolated scopes when not needed, in case need other interaction with items using other scope methods in controller