# AngularJS - compiled html in tootilp

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, angularjs-ng-repeat, angular-ui

I am  trying to use tooltip in ng-repeat based on [AngularJs: grab compiled html and set into tooltip](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20454799/angularjs-grab-compiled-html-and-set-into-tooltip)

However I a somehow not able to make it work.
My html-

```
 <tr ng-repeat="row in docDetails">
<td class="useBootstrap uploadedDocs">
<div class="useBootstrap col-sm-2" upload-info="row" index="{{$index}}">
<p tooltip-html-unsafe="{{tooltips[$index]  }}"> {{ row.FileName | limitTo: 15 }}{{row.FileName.length > 15 ? '...' : ''}}</p>
```

My directive

```
app.directive('uploadInfo', function ($compile, $timeout) {
/* wrap in root element so we can get final innerHTML*/
var tipTemplate = '<div> {{row.FileName}} injected in the tooltip </p><div>';

return {
    link: function (scope, el, attrs) {
        var tipComp = $compile(tipTemplate)(scope)
        $timeout(function () {
            scope.tooltips[attrs.index] = tipComp.html()

        });
    }
}
```

});

Controller i have declared

```
$scope.tooltips = [];
```

Can you tell me if I am missing anything?

Comment: what version of angular-ui are you using? Current version supports html without all this fuss

Comment: @charlietfl AngularJS v1.2.24 - does it support in this version?

Comment: that's the angular version, not the directive version

Comment: Sorry, version of which directive did you ask? im not sure how to check it

Comment: I'm sorry...it's actual a module...angular-ui module. Has a bunch of directives in it of which tooltip is one and why I was thinking directive

Comment: wow, i only have bootstrap and angular min included.if there is a link, can u please help with it?

Comment: https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/tooltip Assumed that was what you were using since it is tagged `angular-ui`

Comment: http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/ui-bootstrap-tpls-0.7.0.min.js" this is another include I have, isnt this sufficient to use the tooltip?

Comment: I think so. Is an old version though. Current one supports html per the docs. Not sure if it is compatible with 1.2 angular though which is also failry old. Funny...I didn't notice until now that I'm the one that answered question you linked to

Comment: :) u did guide me in the right direction, i didnt even get my basics right, I had not injected ui.bootstrap But I get Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr]  .. angular.module("app", ['angularFileUpload'], ['ui.bootstrap']); is this wrong?

Comment: yes..one array not two` ['angularFileUpload','ui.bootstrap']

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/84108/discussion-between-adarsh-k-and-charlietfl).